# Can I use ionic/storage on a service-worker sync?

Tags: ionic-framework, service-worker, indexeddb, web-sql, ionic-storage

I'm using `@ionic/storage` on my project to store HTTP requests when the client is **offline**. Then, when the client back **online** the `service-worker` starts to call the requests stored on the storage.

**The problem is:**
on my `service-worker`, I'm looking at the `indexeddb`, while on the ionic app the `@ionic/storage` deals with the storage availability.

```
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
      name: '_db',
      driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql']
    })
```

where on iPhone X `@ionic/storage` is using `websql`!

who can I use `@ionic/storage` on my `service-worker` so it's the same database always?